# Windows server application pool

Tags: windows, iis, iis-6

How to delete applications from the application pools I tried to stop the application and again remove it but still says that it has 3 applications running.

Comment: What's the Windows version you are using? There are commends to reveal which are the remaining applications, so that you can move them to other pools before removing this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt to move the application to another application pool on IIS.

1. You need to create a new application pool: Open IIS Manager, right click on Application Pools and select option Add Application Pool.
2. Right-click the newly created application pool again and click the Recycling... option.
3. Right-click the original application pool, then click the "View Application" option, select the application that needs to change the application pool, right-click to change.

For more information, please refer [this article](https://success.outsystems.com/Support/Enterprise_Customers/Maintenance_and_Operations/Move_an_app_to_another_application_pool_on_IIS).